# Converting void* to byte array

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I need to convert a void * which will be having a bitmap data. The void* is returned from a cpp function and what I need to do is to convert this void* which is passed to Jni and display this as a bitmap in Java.

```
Void * buffer = CppClass->getbuffer();
ByteArray byte[];
```

byte = the contents of void*;

Comment: you should learn c/c++ basics ... reinterpret_cast should help

Comment: Do you have any idea how big that buffer is? And more important, how much valid data it contains?

Comment: I have tried to cast void * to jbytearray. But in android side I need Byte[].

Comment: The raw data has been written into file. The data size depends on the image size @Deduplicator

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is the natural cast to use when going back from `void*`, because it expresses the intent. and high level language is used primarily to communicate to humans, not to the compiler. still opinions differ and it's not technically wrong to use `static_cast` (it does exactly the same here), just very sub-optimal in terms of human communication, which is the main point of the named casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since java do not have `void*` and jni do not have `ByteArray`, it's not clear what's your execution environment.

Since the source of problem is the void* pixel map, I would assume you want to create a java Bitmap object with the pixels, with a mix of JNI and Java code.

First look at the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class, there is a convenient function named `copyPixelsFromBuffer`, looks like useful, it takes a [Buffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/Buffer.html).

Second, look at JNI function [NewDirectByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/jni-14.html#NewDirectByteBuffer), it takes a C pointer and create a `ByteBuffer`, which is also a Buffer needed by `Bitmap`.

Now it becomes clear, you just need to:

- Create `ByteBuffer` with the pixel buffer with JNI code
- Pass/return that `ByteBuffer` to Java land
- Fill a `Bitmap` with such `ByteBuffer`.
- Display it with `ImageView` or your paint routine.

P.S. It's left to OP's excise to handle object referencing to be GC friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Void * is returned from cpp layer which is JPEG data and I need this image data  in Java layer through the Jni.

Comment: Java do not handle void*, the closest thing you get is a long integer to hold the pointer address, but strictly speaking it's UD. What I suggest above is to pass a ByteBuffer to java and create the Bitmap in java side, which is less messy than creating a Bitmap with JNI calling lots of Java's object methods.

Comment: If I am returning ByteBuffer to the java side from Jni, which type of return type can I use for JNI function.

Comment: your JNI function should return jobject, note that you need to manage the object reference and the real underlying buffer memory, to make GC happy. But doing proper object reference is another BIG question.